# Installing the wkhtmltopdf command line

Tags: macos, command-line, pdf

I'd like to make a pdf out of an webpage. For this purpose, I am trying to install the command line `wkhtmltopdf` on my Mac.

I tried `brew install wkhtmltopdf` and got `Error: No available formula for wkhtmltopdf`

I looked at [this webpage](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) hoping to find the name of the "package" (might not be the right word) in which `wkhtmltopdf` is but it didn't quite help.

How to install the command line `wkhtmltopdf` on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the precompiled OSX packages available on [their website](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html):

[32-bit](http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_osx-carbon-i386.pkg) / [64-bit](http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_osx-cocoa-x86-64.pkg)

The current stable version is 0.12.2.1, which was released on January 19, 2015. There is not available testing version for OSX.